# android keyboard moves tabs

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

So I have an Ionic/Phonegap app that I just built using `ionic start myApp tabs` then I added an input on one of the views. When I focus the input using an android emulator or device, the keyboard come up but so do the tabs. Do I have to explicitly hide the tabs whenever the keyboard is active on android? I would think this would be a common issue but I haven't seen any complaints. Do I just have a bad project or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the activity properties in the manifest.xml

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

Look at the example:
http://rickluna.com/wp/2014/03/phonegap-3-adjustpan-with-fullscreen-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Add following css classes in your Style.ccs

```
/* Hide bottom tab bar when keyboard appears*/
.keyboard-open .has-tabs {
    bottom: 0;
}

body.keyboard-open .has-footer {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

above css classes will do the trick of hiding bottom tab bar when keyboard appears.