# How to prevent the keyboard altering the content layout in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a list with a search box, when the user taps the search box the keyboard shows up but the problem is that it moves the list up with it.

How can I make the keyboard to show up without altering the content layout?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820088/how-to-prevent-keyboard-push-up-webview-at-ios-app-using-phonegap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I later had the same problem with buttons at the bottom of the page that moved with the keyboard, then I just found out this question: [android keyboard moves tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555100/android-keyboard-moves-tabs)

The answer is the same, edit the **AndroidManifest.xml** at platforms/android to change the activity properties:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

And that's it.